# Write to file outside .jar

Tags: java, jar, filewriter, bufferedwriter

My project structure:

```
project
     out
        file.txt
        myjar.jar
                 Main.class
```

My code snippet (that doesn't find the file.txt):

```
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt", true));

output.append(player.toString());
output.close();
```

How do I make it find file.txt and append text to file.txt ?

Comment: May be this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: Have your tried to run this and what was the error? When using file paths in Java and your path used is relative. Being that your path is relative its relative to the Jar or working directory. You should be able to find the file without a problem. Unless the working directory is set differently which in case you can use play with this [How to get the current working directory in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-in-java/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an idea of the current working directory associated with every process on a computer. When a process starts, it usually has a current working directory. This applies to the JVM process (the process that starts when you run the command `java` on your computer) as well.

The *relative* paths that you specify in various IO class methods are with respect to this current working directory. Here's what the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) of `java.io.File` says:

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative
>   pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named
>   by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in
>   which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

So, what is important is to use the correct working directory **when you invoke `java`**. Relative paths (like your `file.txt`) are those that do not begin with a leading '/' or a drive letter.

Here is an example:

### Foo.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Foo.java"))) {
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        } 
    }
}
```

This class, when run, will try to find `Foo.java` itself and output its first line, which is: `import java.io.BufferedReader;`.

1. Compile this to `Foo.class`.
2. Say, folder where `Foo.class` is stored on your (Linux) computer is `/tmp`.
3. You are now on a terminal in `/tmp` => `java Foo`.This should print the first line as expected.
4. `cd $HOME`.
5. `java -cp /tmp Foo` (this is because your class is still in /tmp)

This fails with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Foo.java (No
>   such file or directory)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native
>   Method)   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:138)  at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:93)   at
>   java.io.FileReader.(FileReader.java:58)     at
>   Foo.main(Foo.java:10)

This is because it tries to find `Foo.java` in current working directory, which is `$HOME` and `Foo.java` itself is in some other folder (`/tmp`). What is true of `BufferedReader` is also true of `BufferedWriter` in your case.

So, you should run this program **from a folder where `file.txt` resides**:

1. `cd project/out`
2. `java -cp myjar.jar Main`

A better idea is to always know the location of the file you want to write to. That way, your program may get tied to a particular path on a particular type of computer, but at least you can run it from anywhere on that computer without problems.